# Why can't I get my image hover effect to work like I want it to work?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm building a webpage for school now I build a lactose free page
with some hover effect, now I want to make my txt box bigger so it doesn't look small.
So I want more width on the appearing box so I can put more tekst inside it as well
only now its to narrow and when it gets longer its behind the image below :-/
At the end I want 2 rows with the ingredients and under it the steps to make it.

```css
/* CSS Document */

* {
      margin:  0px;
      padding: 0px;
      border:  0px;
  }



                          /*Body*/

body {
      font-family:"Helvetica scary";
      background-image: url("../images/background2.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

                           /*Logo*/

.logo {
      text-align: center;
      clear: both;
      opacity: 1;
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}



                           /*Topnav*/

.topnav {
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding: 5px 0px 5px 0;
      border-bottom: dotted #66A761;
      border-top: dotted #66A761;
      position: relative;
      text-align:center;
}

.topnav ul {
      display: inline;
      text-align: center;
}

.topnav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 47px;
      padding: 0;
      text-indent: 0;
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
      -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
      -o-transition: all 0.2s;
      transition: all 0.2s;
}


.topnav a {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:link {
      color: #9F257D;
}

.topnav a:hover {
      color: #66A761;
}

.topnav input {
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 0 5px;
      right: 20px;
      border-radius: 25px;
      border: 0;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
      width: 150px;
      opacity: 0.7;
      position: flex;
      color: #FFF;
    
}


.topnav button {
      background-color:#66A761;
      border-radius: 25px;
      padding: 5px;
      color: #9FFF;
      opacity: 0.9;
      font-style:oblique;
}




                          /*submenu*/


.topnav ul li ul {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
      padding: 5px 5px;
      z-index: 1;
}

.topnav ul li:hover ul li {
      display: block;
      z-index: 1;
}

.topnav li a:active {
      color: #ffffff;
    }

.topnav ul li ul li {
      display: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 2px;
      
}
                         /*content*/

.container {
     width: 930px;
     margin: 70px auto 0;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.container .box {
     position: relative;
     width: 300px;
     height: 228px;
     background: #555;
     margin: 5px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     display: inline-block;
}

.container .box .imgbox {
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
}

.container .box .imgbox img {
     transition: transform 2s;
}

.container .box:hover .imgbox img {
     transform: scale(1.2);
}

.container .box .details {
     position: absolute;
     top: 10px;
     left: 10px;
     bottom: 10px;
     right: 10px;
     backgound: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
     transform: scaleY(0);
     transition: transform .5s;
}

.container .box:hover .details {
     transform: scaleY(1);
}

.container .box .details .content {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     text-align: center;
     padding: 15px;
     color: #FFF;
}

.container .box .details .content h2{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-size: 20px;
     color: #FFF;
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
     opacity: 0.7;
     border-radius: 5px;
}

.container .box .details .content p{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-size: 15px;
     color: #FFF;
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
     opacity: 0.7;
     border-radius: 5px;
}

.container .box .details .content a {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-size: 20px;
     color: #FFF;
     text-decoration: none;
}


                         /*Footer*/

.footer {
     clear: both;
     margin: 60px 0 0 0;
     padding: 30px;
     text-align: center;

     color :#9F257D;
     border-top: dotted #66A761;
     border-bottom: dotted #66A761;
     opacity: 0.9;
     background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

.footer img {
     padding: 0 5px;
}


                          /*Under Construction*/


@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    
    .wrapper {
        width: 100%
    }

    
                           /*topnav*/
.topnav {
    flex-direction: column;
    
}
    
.topnav ul {
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}   
    
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    
    
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
}

                  
                           /*topnav*/
.topnav {
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 100%;
    align-content: center;
    
}
    
.topnav ul {
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
    
.topnav li {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
        
}
    
.topnav input {
    
}
    

                         /*Text Area*/  
.main {
    max-width:100%;
}


                         /*content*/

.container {
    max-width: 100%;
}
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    
    .banner {
        visibility: hidden;
        max-width: 300px;
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>lactosevrij</title>
<link href="css/lactosevrij.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>  
    
<div class="wrapper">

                           <!--Logo-->
<div class="logo">  
  <header>
   <a href="index.html"><img src="images/fflogo1.png" alt=""/></a>
  </header>
</div>
    

    
                           <!--Topnav-->
<div class="topnav">
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="recepten.html">Recepten</a>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="lactosevrij.html">Lactosevrij</a></li>
             <li><a href="suikervrij.html">Suikervrij</a></li>
             <li><a href="glutenvrij.html">Glutenvrij</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="varianten.html">Varianten</a>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="basis1.html">Basis</a></li>
             <li><a href="standaard1.html">Standaard</a></li>
             <li><a href="luxe1.html">Luxe</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="overons.html">Over ons</a></li>
   </ul> 
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
        <button type="submit"><i class="fafa-search"></i>Search</button>
  </nav>
</div>  


<!--containers-->
<div class="container">
    

                           <!--Lactosevrij recept 1-->
<div class="box">
  <div class="imgbox">
      <img src="images/lactosevrijpage/caponata.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Spaghetti Carbonara</h2>
<p><br>200 g gerookt ontbijtspek
<br>25 g ongezouten roomboter
<br>2 el traditionele olijfolie 
<br>1 teen knoflook
<br>2 middelgrote eieren
<br>300 g spaghetti
<br>50 g Parmigiano Reggiano
<br>50 g Pecorino Romano
<br>1 tl versgemalen zwarte peper</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
                           <!--Lactosevrij recept 2-->
<div class="box">
  <div class="imgbox">
      <img src="images/lactosevrijpage/geroosterde-garnalen.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <div class="content">  
        <h2>geroosterde-garnalen</h2>
        <p><br>450 g diepvries rauwe en ongepelde reuzengarnalen (zak, ontdooid)
          <br> 1 teen knoflook 
          <br> 1 citroen
          <br> 1 medium handsinaasappel
          <br> 3 el traditionele olijfolie
          <br> 1 takje rozemarijn (naaldjes gerist)</p>
             
        
        <a href="suikervrij.html"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
                           <!--Lactosevrij recept 3-->
<div class="box">
  <div class="imgbox">
      <img src="images/lactosevrijpage/goulash.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Goulash</h2>
<p><br>250 g champignons
<br>25 g ongezouten roomboter
<br>350 g runderreepjes (schaal)
<br>1 el pikante paprikapoeder
<br>295 g gegrilde rode paprika's (potje)
<br>375 g tomato frito (tomatensaus, pakje)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
                          <!--Lactosevrij recept 4-->

<div class="box">
  <div class="imgbox">
      <img src="images/lactosevrijpage/kippensoep.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <div class="content">
      <a href="lactosevrij.html"><h2>Kippensoep</h2></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
                           <!--Lactosevrij recept 5-->
<div class="box">
  <div class="imgbox">
      <img src="images/lactosevrijpage/lactosevrije-chocolade-cake.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <div class="content">
             <a href="suikervrij.html"><h2>Chocolade Cake</h2></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
                           <!--Lactosevrij recept 6-->
<div class="box">
  <div class="imgbox">
      <img src="images/lactosevrijpage/mexicaanse-burritos.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <div class="content">
            <a href="glutenvrij.html"><h2>Mexicaanse Burritos</h2></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    

                           <!--Lactosevrij recept 7-->
<div class="box">
  <div class="imgbox">
      <img src="images/lactosevrijpage/mexicaanse-taco-salade.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <div class="content">
      <a href="lactosevrij.html"><h2>Mexicaanse Taco Salade</h2></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
                           <!--Lactosevrij recept 8-->
<div class="box">
  <div class="imgbox">
      <img src="images/lactosevrijpage/rosbief-met-groenten-uit-de-oven.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <div class="content">
             <a href="suikervrij.html"><h2>Rosbief Met Groente</h2></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
                           <!--Lactosevrij recept 9-->
<div class="box">
  <div class="imgbox">
      <img src="images/lactosevrijpage/zalm-teriyaki.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <div class="content">
            <a href="glutenvrij.html"><h2>Zalm Teriyaki</h2></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  
</div>
    
    
    
                           <!--Footer-->    
<div class="footer">
   <div class="icons">
     <a href="facebook.html"><img src="images/social-media-icons/facebook.png" alt=""/></a>
     <a href="googlemaps.html"><img src="images/social-media-icons/google-maps.png" alt=""/></a>
     <a href="gmail.html"><img src="images/social-media-icons/gmail.png" alt=""/></a>
   </div>
</div>
</div>  
    

    
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-4.3.1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a lot wrong with your Site. Using <br> to get breaks and position: absolute on a lot of things makes it really hard to get elements fixed. You should absolutely check out CSS Grid and CSS Flex-Box. For the specific Problem with the Hover-Effect you should check out max-height and overflow. Easiest solution without rewriting the whole Code i could think of would be: max-height: 100% to the "container"-class and overflow-y: scroll to the "box"-class

Comment: that would not look very nice tho. As i said rewriting the whole Code without <br> and position: absolute would be the best solution

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem is how the animated boxes are too narrow when they show up by hovering over each "box" in your grid. I believe adding `width: 100%;` to the `.container .box .details .content` element should sort that, hopefully.

If you're learning, you could also take this opportunity to get acquainted with the [CSS Grid property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). Good luck!

*Follow-up reply from OP's comments:*

Seems to me like you need to learn more about the box model, there's a good resource for you [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model).

To guide you more specifically, first off I would use the [`*` selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_all.asp) to add the following property to all elements in your project, like so: `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`, just to make your life easier.

On the `.details` **and** `.content` elements, remove all absolute positioning and `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left` properties, as well as any `transform: translate`. Note, this might also be a good opportunity for you to detect any unnecessary elements and clean up your code, if you want.

Now, on the `.container .box` element, change the `height` property into a `min-height` property. That way, if there's more content the container will increase in height with it.

NOTE: This might make your grid to not look as uniform as before, to which end I'd suggest you to play around with your flex properties or, even better, the CSS Grid reference I've linked for you in my initial answer.

Comment: yea exactly what i ment sorry for the late reply , width: 100%; is better but i need to add more steps to the txt and now when it gets to big and the txt dissapear under the pictures under it

Comment: so how owuld i be able to get the tekst in front of the image below ?